# How to create an observable with interval

Tags: rxjs

Does anyone know how to create an observable which emits items at equal intervals. The only catch is the first element should always be returned immediately.

Here is my current code. I just need the first element to be returned immediately.

```
var source = Rx.Observable.interval(2000);

source.subscribe(function(item){
  console.log(item);
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *timer*. It can get two parameters. The first is the initial delay - 0 for immediate value. The second is the interval.

```
Rx.Observable.timer(0, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks! My actual usecase was to emit items from my own Observable. Say source1 is my observable and source2 is observable returned from the timer function then I would use zip to emit items from my observable. Wondering if there is a shortcut in rxjs for this...

var source3 = Rx.Observable.zip(
  source1,
  source2,
  function(item1, item2){
    return item1;
  }
)

Comment: There are some alternatives but nothing shorter I can come up :/
You can just write it like this: Rx.Observable.zip(source1, source2, x => x)